# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to inner join on an update query but am getting an error about my syntax, to my knowledge it looks fine (I maybe looking over something) all the tables are there which I have included in this post for you.

**My error**

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FROM applications INNER JOIN jobs ON
>   applications.app'

**My SQL**

```
 $sql = "UPDATE applications 
         SET    applications.application_status = 1 
         FROM   applications
         INNER JOIN jobs 
         ON applications.application_job = jobs.job_id 
         WHERE  applications.application_user = ?
         AND jobs.job_enabled=1";
```

**Jobs table I am inner joining**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (
  `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_description` text NOT NULL,
  `job_duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_category` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `job_user` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_employer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `job_enabled` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `job_startdate` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Applications table I am updating**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `applications` (
  `application_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `application_user` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `application_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `application_job` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `application_status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `application_enabled` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are joining the jobs table in the query? To me it seems like it isn't necessary.

Comment: I will eventually use AND jobs.job_enabled=1 to make sure the job is enabled hence the reason to join. I should've included that in my OP, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support [FROM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) clause in `Update` Statement. Unlike SQL Server, your `join` statement needs to be before `SET` as well. You could simply do this instead:

```
$sql = "UPDATE applications a
        INNER JOIN jobs j ON a.application_job = j.job_id                             
        SET    a.application_status = 1 
        WHERE  a.application_user = ?
          AND  j.jobs_enabled = 1"
```